# Run SQL query for each value in table

Tags: sql

I have a table called delegation_table as follows:

```
delegator | delegatee

josh      | ryan
carl      | nick
sam       | john
```

There is another table called permission_table as follows:

```
username | location | branch   | office

josh     | usa      |New York  | downtown
carl     | asia     | India    | north
sam      | usa      |California| midtown
```

For each of the `delegators` from the `delegation_table`, I want to get their details from the `permission_table` and insert a row with the same details with `username` as the respective `delegatee`.

For example - I want to find details of josh which is:

```
josh     | usa      |New York  | downtown
```

and insert this row in the `permission_table`:

```
ryan     | usa      |New York  | downtown
```

Something like this:

```
insert into permission_table
(username, location, branch, office)
select 'ryan' as username, location, branch, office
from permission_table
where username = 'josh'
```

But I don't want to hard code the values and want to run this for every `delegator` in `delegation_table`. How do I do that??

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a `join`:

```
insert into permission_table (username, location, branch, office)
    select dt.delegatee, location, branch, office
    from permission_table pt join
         delegation_table dt
         on dt.delegator = pt.username;
```